# SiriKit queries trigger web search

Tags: swift, xcode8, ios10, sirikit

Any request that I make to send money to a contact through Siri triggers a web search, passing the voice input to Safari (i.e. "Send $100 to Bob").

I have enables Siri in my app capabilities and have added the INSendPaymentIntent to my info.plist files.

This even occurs for UnicornChat (Apple's sample project) where iMessage is prompted when attempting to send a message through UnicornChat. The extension UI for Unicorn Chat appears briefly and is then overridden by iMessage's.

Could this possibly be an issue on Apple's side, or is there a potential fix I can make?

Answer (score 1):

My Sirikit extension was working until yesterday, now I'm having your same behavior. Probably they're preparing for beta4.

Answer (score 0):

We were having this same issue in the app I work on. The way we got it to start working properly is to make sure you always include a valid `paymentRecord` with all completions that take an `INSendPaymentIntentResponse` as a parameter. `paymentRecord` is an optional property, however, the discussion notes in the documentation state this...

> Always assign an object to this property that contains as much
>   information as you have about the transaction. Siri communicates this
>   information to the user during the confirmation phase and after your
>   Intents extension handles the payment.

https://developer.apple.com/reference/intents/insendpaymentintentresponse/1638625-paymentrecord